# How to a thread performs Binary Search on the Prefix-Sum array

Tags: arrays, multithreading, gpu, prefix-sum

In the context of Parallel programming and GPU, we have an array that is called `Prefix-Sum` array. In Dynamic Mapping, each thread performs a binary search on the Prefix-Sum to find the corresponding Work-Item.

[image: Thread to Work-Item]

It is a question for me, How a thread know for which work-item or work-unit will be searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread 5 does a binary search for its own identity 5

```
5 <25
5 < 9
5 > 3
4 (work item 2)
```

Comment: From your description it seems like that is what happens.

Comment: It is an example to the sake of clarity, I like to know what is happening in the real application.